# The captcha is not working for my Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js, captcha

I have been trying to make a captcha on my discord bot. I am entirely new to JavaScript and I'm struggling to understand the issues. But, that's not the point. When I do 'ri-verification' on the chat, it does not work. It doesn't log anything either. It just does nothing with no errors.

Code:

```js
    const Discord = require('discord.js-12');

    const client = new Discord.Client();

    const prefix = 'ri-';

    const Captcha = require("@haileybot/captcha-generator");

    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
    });
    let captcha = new Captcha();
    console.log(captcha.value);
     

    const path = require("path"),
        fs = require("fs")



    captcha.PNGStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, `${captcha.value}.png`)));
    captcha.JPEGStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, `${captcha.value}.jpeg`)));
     
    client.on('message', async message => {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

        const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        if (command === 'verification') {
            function verifyHuman(msg) {
                let captcha = new Captcha();
                msg.channel.send(
                    "**Enter the text shown in the image below:**",
                    new Discord.MessageAttachment(captcha.JPEGStream, "captcha.jpeg")
                );
                let collector = msg.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === msg.author.id);
                collector.on("collect", m => {
                    if (m.content.toUpperCase() === captcha.value) msg.channel.send("Verified Successfully!");
                    else msg.channel.send("Failed Verification!");
                    collector.stop();
                });
            };

        }
    });
            

    client.login('');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting a function inside an if statement. Pretty sure you cannot do that. Either put the function outside the statement or put the contents inside it in the if statement.

I'll explain it further in your DMs :)